# Does the assume_role {} assume a role during apply or plan step?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm assuming a role from Github Actions Runner using OIDC. This successfully assumes the role in AWS. I then have the assume_role {} block configured in the aws provider.

The role in the assume_role {} block has all the required iam permissions to manage AWS Resources, and the trust relationship that allows the Github Actions Runner role to assume it. During the terraform plan, it fails.

Code snippet from provider "aws" {} block

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/deploy_role_XXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/github_runner/terraform-plan is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: x_secret because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action
```

This above error indicates that the role is never assumed.

Comment: Does any of the permissions policies have anything related to using Secrets Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a single provider block in all your terraform files? Because if you have one provider with this assume_role and the others have not, you might get inconsistent behaviour.

Terraform should assume the role before it does anything with AWS (including plan and apply) so my best guess is that you have an empty AWS provider block somewhere else that overrides this behaviour.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34616619)

Comment: @LinDu: While it does ask a clarifying question, it also clearly provides guidance based on the presumed answer, and thus seems like an appropriate answer to me.